# Is there a way to access older "Missing Moment" strips of Sister Claire webcomic?

Tags: webcomics, sister-claire

[*Sister Claire*](http://www.sisterclaire.com/) webcomic lately was running a "character backstory" strips called "Missing Moment". However, those strips seem to disappear from the main comic's timeline - the latest one shows, but none of the previous ones appear if you flip to previous strips/

Is there a way to access older "Missing Moment" strips somehow? Or is the creator deliberately removing them to use as printed version extra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, the 'missing moment' strips you're referring to can be accessed from the [Archive](http://www.sisterclaire.com/archive.php) page.

You can also view them sequentially by clicking [here](http://www.sisterclaire.com/missingmoments.php?id=408) and using the "next" button.

Comment: Damn. I'm so used to reading that comic live I didn't even think about archives link. Thanks!

Comment: Also, with the new site structure they now have their own section.